# Convert MathJax formula to image in base64 format

Tags: javascript, c#, base64, mathjax

I'm trying to convert a MathJax formula into png (base64) format. Below is the code and HTML i'm using.

**HTML file:**

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <title></title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <p data-uid="0" class="morTag_a avsnitt">Risikomarginen skal beregnes på følgende måte </p>
<p classid="block-formula"><mjx-container class="MathJax CtxtMenu_Attached_0" jax="CHTML" display="true" tabindex="0" ctxtmenu_counter="0" style="font-size: 117.4%; position: relative;"><mjx-math display="true" class="MJX-TEX" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;"><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D445 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D440 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mo class="mjx-n" space="4"><mjx-c class="mjx-c3D"></mjx-c></mjx-mo><mjx-mn class="mjx-n" space="4"><mjx-c class="mjx-c30"></mjx-c></mjx-mn><mjx-mo class="mjx-n"><mjx-c class="mjx-c2C"></mjx-c></mjx-mo><mjx-mn class="mjx-n" space="2"><mjx-c class="mjx-c30"></mjx-c><mjx-c class="mjx-c33"></mjx-c></mjx-mn><mjx-mo class="mjx-n" space="3"><mjx-c class="mjx-c22C5"></mjx-c></mjx-mo><mjx-mrow space="3"><mjx-mo class="mjx-n"><mjx-c class="mjx-c28"></mjx-c></mjx-mo><mjx-msub><mjx-texatom texclass="ORD"><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D435 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D438 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi></mjx-texatom><mjx-script style="vertical-align: -0.15em;"><mjx-texatom size="s" texclass="ORD"><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D45C TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D453 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D453 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi></mjx-texatom></mjx-script></mjx-msub><mjx-mo class="mjx-n" space="3"><mjx-c class="mjx-c2B"></mjx-c></mjx-mo><mjx-msub space="3"><mjx-texatom texclass="ORD"><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D435 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D438 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi></mjx-texatom><mjx-script style="vertical-align: -0.15em;"><mjx-texatom size="s" texclass="ORD"><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D45D TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D45F TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D456 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D463 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi></mjx-texatom></mjx-script></mjx-msub><mjx-msub><mjx-texatom texclass="ORD"><mjx-mo class="mjx-n"><mjx-c class="mjx-c2B"></mjx-c></mjx-mo><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D435 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D438 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi></mjx-texatom><mjx-script style="vertical-align: -0.15em;"><mjx-texatom size="s" texclass="ORD"><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D453 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D45F TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D456 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi></mjx-texatom></mjx-script></mjx-msub><mjx-mo class="mjx-n" space="3"><mjx-c class="mjx-c2B"></mjx-c></mjx-mo><mjx-msub space="3"><mjx-texatom texclass="ORD"><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D435 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D438 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi></mjx-texatom><mjx-script style="vertical-align: -0.15em;"><mjx-texatom size="s" texclass="ORD"><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D456 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D45B TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D463 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mo class="mjx-n"><mjx-c class="mjx-c2E"></mjx-c></mjx-mo><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D463 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D44E TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D459 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D454 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi></mjx-texatom></mjx-script></mjx-msub><mjx-mo class="mjx-n" space="3"><mjx-c class="mjx-c2B"></mjx-c></mjx-mo><mjx-mi class="mjx-i" space="3"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D447 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D434 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mo class="mjx-n" space="3"><mjx-c class="mjx-c2B"></mjx-c></mjx-mo><mjx-mi class="mjx-i" space="3"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D43E TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D439 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mo class="mjx-n" space="3"><mjx-c class="mjx-c2B"></mjx-c></mjx-mo><mjx-mi class="mjx-i" space="3"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D435 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D439 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mo class="mjx-n"><mjx-c class="mjx-c29"></mjx-c></mjx-mo></mjx-mrow><mjx-mo class="mjx-n" space="3"><mjx-c class="mjx-c2B"></mjx-c></mjx-mo><mjx-mi class="mjx-i" space="3"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D45A TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D44E TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D458 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D460 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mo class="mjx-n"><mjx-c class="mjx-c7B"></mjx-c></mjx-mo><mjx-mn class="mjx-n"><mjx-c class="mjx-c30"></mjx-c></mjx-mn><mjx-mo class="mjx-n"><mjx-c class="mjx-c2C"></mjx-c></mjx-mo><mjx-mn class="mjx-n" space="2"><mjx-c class="mjx-c31"></mjx-c></mjx-mn><mjx-mo class="mjx-n" space="3"><mjx-c class="mjx-c22C5"></mjx-c></mjx-mo><mjx-mi class="mjx-i" space="3"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D435 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-msub><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D438 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-script style="vertical-align: -0.177em; margin-left: -0.026em;"><mjx-texatom size="s" texclass="ORD"><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D452 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D461 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D461 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D45F TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi></mjx-texatom></mjx-script></mjx-msub><mjx-mtext class="mjx-n"><mjx-c class="mjx-c3B"></mjx-c></mjx-mtext><mjx-mn class="mjx-n"><mjx-c class="mjx-c30"></mjx-c></mjx-mn><mjx-mo class="mjx-n"><mjx-c class="mjx-c2C"></mjx-c></mjx-mo><mjx-mn class="mjx-n" space="2"><mjx-c class="mjx-c30"></mjx-c><mjx-c class="mjx-c38"></mjx-c></mjx-mn><mjx-mo class="mjx-n" space="3"><mjx-c class="mjx-c22C5"></mjx-c></mjx-mo><mjx-mi class="mjx-i" space="3"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D439 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-msub><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D434 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-script style="vertical-align: -0.177em;"><mjx-texatom size="s" texclass="ORD"><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D452 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D461 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D461 TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"></mjx-mi><mjx-mi class="mjx-i"><mjx-c class="mjx-c1D45F TEX-I"></mjx-c></mjx-mi></mjx-texatom></mjx-script></mjx-msub><mjx-mo class="mjx-n"><mjx-c class="mjx-c7D"></mjx-c></mjx-mo></mjx-math><mjx-assistive-mml unselectable="on" display="block"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"><mi>R</mi><mi>M</mi><mo>=</mo><mn>0</mn><mo>,</mo><mn>03</mn><mo>⋅</mo><mrow data-mjx-texclass="INNER"><mo data-mjx-texclass="OPEN">(</mo><msub><mrow data-mjx-texclass="ORD"><mi>B</mi><mi>E</mi></mrow><mrow data-mjx-texclass="ORD"><mi>o</mi><mi>f</mi><mi>f</mi></mrow></msub><mo>+</mo><msub><mrow data-mjx-texclass="ORD"><mi>B</mi><mi>E</mi></mrow><mrow data-mjx-texclass="ORD"><mi>p</mi><mi>r</mi><mi>i</mi><mi>v</mi></mrow></msub><msub><mrow data-mjx-texclass="ORD"><mo>+</mo><mi>B</mi><mi>E</mi></mrow><mrow data-mjx-texclass="ORD"><mi>f</mi><mi>r</mi><mi>i</mi></mrow></msub><mo>+</mo><msub><mrow data-mjx-texclass="ORD"><mi>B</mi><mi>E</mi></mrow><mrow data-mjx-texclass="ORD"><mi>i</mi><mi>n</mi><mi>v</mi><mo>.</mo><mi>v</mi><mi>a</mi><mi>l</mi><mi>g</mi></mrow></msub><mo>+</mo><mi>T</mi><mi>A</mi><mo>+</mo><mi>K</mi><mi>F</mi><mo>+</mo><mi>B</mi><mi>F</mi><mo data-mjx-texclass="CLOSE">)</mo></mrow><mo>+</mo><mi>m</mi><mi>a</mi><mi>k</mi><mi>s</mi><mo fence="false" stretchy="false">{</mo><mn>0</mn><mo>,</mo><mn>1</mn><mo>⋅</mo><mi>B</mi><msub><mi>E</mi><mrow data-mjx-texclass="ORD"><mi>e</mi><mi>t</mi><mi>t</mi><mi>å</mi><mi>r</mi></mrow></msub><mtext>;</mtext><mn>0</mn><mo>,</mo><mn>08</mn><mo>⋅</mo><mi>F</mi><msub><mi>A</mi><mrow data-mjx-texclass="ORD"><mi>e</mi><mi>t</mi><mi>t</mi><mi>å</mi><mi>r</mi></mrow></msub><mo fence="false" stretchy="false">}</mo></math></mjx-assistive-mml></mjx-container></p>
<p></p>
<p data-uid="0" class="morTag_m no-text-indent marg">der</p>
<p data-uid="0" class="morTag_m no-text-indent marg">RM = verdien av risikomarginen,</p>
<p data-uid="0" class="morTag_m no-text-indent marg">BE = verdien av beste estimat for den enkelte portefølje beregnet i samsvar med § 3,</p>
<p data-uid="0" class="morTag_m no-text-indent marg">TA = samlede tilleggsavsetninger,</p>
<p data-uid="0" class="morTag_m no-text-indent marg">KF = samlet kursreguleringsfond,</p>
<p data-uid="0" class="morTag_m no-text-indent marg">BF = samlet bufferfond, og</p>
<p data-uid="0" class="morTag_m no-text-indent marg"><span>FA</span><sub class=" sub">ettår</sub><span> = verdien av forsikringsmessige avsetninger for porteføljen for ettårige risikoprodukter beregnet i samsvar med § 3 annet ledd.</span></p>
<table class="textList fotnote avsnitt liste" style="width:100%"><tbody><tr><td data-id="fotnote_0" class="morTag_fn fotnoteNummer"><span class="namedAnchor" data-id="fotnoteNummer_0"></span><span>0</span></td><td class="fotnote" data-id="fotnoteContent_0"><span class="namedAnchor" data-id="fotnoteContent_0"></span><span>Endret ved forskrift </span><a data-id="forskrift/2022-03-30-495" class=" reference" href="/LTI/forskrift/2022-03-30-495">30 mars 2022 nr. 495</a><span>.</span></td></tr></tbody></table>
<div data-id="PARAGRAF_9" class="morTag_p paragraf" id="PARAGRAF_9"></div>
<div data-level="1" data-id="KAPITTEL_1" data-refid="kap1" class="morTag_b kapittel" id="KAPITTEL_1"></div>
<a class="namedAnchor" name="kap2"></a>
                
            </body></html>
```

- Above html is a small section of https://lovdata.no/dokument/SF/forskrift/2018-11-09-1689

**Code:**

```
public class MathJaxToBase64 {
    public static string ConvertToBase64(string math) {
        var tex = new TeXInput(math);
        var node = new MathNode(tex);
        var settings = new MathJaxSettings {
            SVG = false,
            CSS = false,
            Font = null,
            Ex = 6,
            Em = 12
        };
        var output = new TextOutput(node, settings);
        var png = output.RenderAsPng();
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(png);
        return $"data:image/png;base64,{base64}";
    }
}
```

I have installed the MathJax library properly but when I try to import below, I'm getting an error saying that they cannot be imported. Please tell me how to make it work and convert the MathJax formula to an image(base64)

```
using MathJax;
using MathJax.Node;
using MathJax.Typesetting;
```